# Nested lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

How can I get the Count of Person whose name equals "john" from a List using lambda expressions.
How can I create my lambda expression?

```
List<Persons> persons;
person.Where(p=>p.Name.Equals("John");
```

Now do I do a count on the returned List or should I nest it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. Use the overload of the `Count` method that takes an expression:

```
int cnt = person.Count(p => p.Name.Equals("John"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
person.Where(p=>p.Name.Equals("John")).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Person> persons;
/* code that populates persons list */
int count = persons.Where(p=>p.Name.Equals("John")).Count();
```